# save image from uiimage view after transferring view

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a simple UIImageView who's frame is dynamically scaled by the user dragging on the screen. This causes the image to stretch/compress on the screen, which is what I want.

Now, I want to save the resiling image that is all stretched/squished, but if I simply save the image from the view, I get the un-altered image.

How do I persist the frame adjustments and have a new image generated?

_mike

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself. The following code does what I need.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Thanks.